# Calculating the width/height of strings on python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to calculate the height/width of various strings (given a font and size). I'm trying to follow [this example](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/api/afm_api.html). I have written the following:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
import os.path
afm_fname = os.path.join(rcParams['datapath'], 'fonts', 'afm', 'ptmr8a.afm')

from matplotlib.afm import AFM
with open(afm_fname) as fh:
    afm = AFM(fh)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 2, in <module>
    afm = AFM(fh)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\afm.py", line 337, in __init__
    parse_afm(fh)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\afm.py", line 323, in parse_afm
    _sanity_check(fh)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\afm.py", line 102, in _sanity_check
    if not line.startswith(b'StartFontMetrics'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes
```

Any help is much appreciated. Note, I do not need to use matplotlib, so if there is a better way to get these numbers in python, I am open to other options (if it matters, the text will eventually be used in an SVG).

I have tried using freetype-py too, but have run into trouble getting further than 'import freetype' - I think due to problems with freetype on windows, it can't seem to find the appropriate dlls. There are various issues about it on the github repo, but haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. Whatever solution: any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x? I just tried the code and it runs under Python 2.7 for me, but not under Python 3.6.

Comment: Yes, I'm using python 3. I suspected it is something to do with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a python 2 to 3 problem (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data) with `AFM` hard coded binary string in their code. One solution is to open `afm_fname` in binary mode explicitly, if this is OK to you.

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
import os.path
afm_fname = os.path.join(rcParams['datapath'],
                        'fonts', 'afm', 'ptmr8a.afm')

from matplotlib.afm import AFM
with open(afm_fname, 'rb') as fh:
    afm = AFM(fh)
afm.string_width_height('What the heck?')

# (6220.0, 694)
```

The string method `startswith` works for both text and binary data in python 2. So the code above works for python 2 too. Python 3 distinguish text and binary data. So `'rb'` is necessary. The example in `matplotlib` might need an update or a note.

Comment: I created a PR on to change the example in the documentation: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10467/files

Comment: oh this is perfect! yes I read there was a difference with how the `startswith` method, but couldn't quite figure out what to do to fix it. Many thanks. Very clear